# Integration of Jasmine in ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, jasmine, ember-cli

I want to use Jasmine in place of qunit in an EmberJS project build with ember-cli. I found few samples to integrate Jasmine in EmberJS, but none with ember-cli.

Does an addon exist to use Jasmine with ember-cli?

Thanks for your help.

Frédéric

Comment: None that I know of, Qunit is the way to go with cli, a mocha adapter is being considered not sure about the timeframe.

Comment: To my understanding jasmine isn't being bothered with due to async test  being a genuine PITA.